# Is it safe to upgrade to 18.04 on a dual-boot Windows 7 machine

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, windows-7

I have an installation of ubuntu 17.1 in dual boot with Windows 7 pro on a homebuilt AMD machine.  It has been working fine both ways.  Now, when I log in to ubuntu, it tells me that I should upgrade to 18.04, and gives me a one-click to do the upgrade.  Since the Windows boot now passes through grub2, which was described as a beta when I first installed ubuntu, my question is whether doing the ubuntu upgrade, without changing anything else might disrupt the dual boot.

Comment: There was no 2017.January release of Ubuntu, so I'm assuming you mean Ubuntu 17.10 (2017-October release that is EOL).  Yes you should upgrade asap after of course backing up your system.  You should ensure your 17.10 is fully-upgraded, then release-upgrade.  Note: Some time after a release reaches EOL it's archives are moved which complicates things, so if you have troubles this would be the primary cause (which will show in the fully-upgrading 17.10 step).

Comment: As to your concern: each disk only has a single MBR (master-boot-record, or the first 512 bytes of the physical drive) and it reads like Ubuntu 17.10 owns that record. Upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 will not impact that ownership, in fact the MBR itself (grub stage 0) won't be touched by the release-upgrade; only later stages found in /boot/grub/ will be re-written to use the 18.04 kernel instead of 17.10 which won't impact your windows 7 as long as your windows 7 system isn't hibernated (ie. is shutdown normally)

Answer (score 1):

**"Safe" is a relative term.** That makes this a hard question to answer.

IF your system is in proper working order,
AND IF you have taken the basic preventative measures to avoid common release-upgrade problems,
AND IF you have proper backups,
AND IF you're not in a hurry, you have a stable network connection, and reliable power supply,
...then your release-upgrade is very, very likely to go quickly and smoothly.

We recommend a full backup of all your data on both OS before making major changes (including upgrades) to either OS. This site is littered with the shattered dreams and lost data of folks who failed to take basic precautions...and got badly burned.

In 13 years of using Ubuntu, I've needed my backups exactly once (my mistake, not Ubuntu's). But that day I was very, very happy to have those backups.

If your system has some kind of problem that you hope a release-upgrade will fix, STOP. Fix all problems before release-upgrading. Release-upgrades usually make unfixed problems worse.

**Yes, it's possible that a release-upgrade might break a dual-boot.** It's rare, but it does happen. It's often caused by some underlying problem. And it's usually pretty easy to fix.